# Unable to export pdf using DOMPDF

Tags: php, mysql

**Code Modified**

```
<?php
            require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

               $date=date("m/d/Y");
               echo "Today Date Is = ";
               echo "$date";
               echo "<h1><center>order status </center></h3>";

            include("../../../../../../../inetpub/wwwroot/dbcon/connection.php");

             $content="";

            if(isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
              include("../../../../../../../inetpub/wwwroot/dbcon/connection.php");
              $content .=  "<h3>Customer order</h3>";
              $search=htmlspecialchars($_POST['search']);
              $selectcondition = "SELECT * FROM customer.order where DATE='".$search."'"; 
              $check=mysql_query($selectcondition,$con);
              $fetch=mysql_fetch_row($check); 

               if(!$fetch)                          
               {

                  $content .=   "<font color='red'>";
                  $content .=    "<br>";
              $content .=  "No order Found In The Database"; 
              $content .=  "<br>";
                  $content .=   "</font>";
              return $content;

            }

             else //if the above condition is flase !
                 {

               $sql= "select * from customer.order  where DATE='".$_POST['search']."'";
                   $mydata=mysql_query($sql,$con);

 $content .=  "<table class='mytable' width='100%' height='10%' border='1' cellspacing='0'>

                             <tr>
                              <th>DATE</th>
                              <th>ORDER</th>
                              <th>CUSTNAME</th>
                              <th>COMMENTS</th>

                             </tr>";

                while($records = mysql_fetch_array($mydata))

                {

                            $content .= "<tr>";
                            $content .="<td>" . $records['TIMESTAMPS'] . "&nbsp;</td>";
                            $content .= "<td>" . $records['ORDER']. "&nbsp;</td>";
                            $content .= "<td>" . $records['CUSTNAME'] . "&nbsp;</td>";
                            $content .="<td align='center'>";
                            $content .= '<textarea  name="textarea" cols="100"  >'.$records['COMMENTS'].'</textarea><br>'; 

                            $content .=  "</td>";

                }

                     "</table>";

            }
        }

          $html= $content;
          $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
          $dompdf->load_html($html);
          $dompdf->render();
          $dompdf->stream("order.php");

          ?>
```

I have modified my code with recent changes, I have removed **content function** and took everything in **$content** variable.

after that a corrupted PDF is generated.
Please help me how do i fix it .

Thanks again for you reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You this wrong

```
$dompdf->load_html($html);
```

According to the [docs](https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/Usage)

```
$html =
  '<html><body>'.
  '<p>Put your html here, or generate it with your favourite '.
  'templating system.</p>'.
  '</body></html>';
```

and you are using echo all the time to output the content. try creating the object first and then `return` so it does actually exist in the variable :)  without echo and them it should work.

So you code will look like this fx::

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    include("../../../../../../../inetpub/wwwroot/dbcon/connection.php");

     $content = "<h3>Turnover For Apria</h3>";

     $search=htmlspecialchars($_POST['search']);
     $selectcondition = "SELECT * FROM customer.order where DATE='".$search."'"; //Select Query Which check the whether the TURNOVER for the given INCIDENT is exit or not.

     $check=mysql_query($selectcondition,$con);
     $fetch=mysql_fetch_row($check); 

    if(!$fetch)                         //If checklist for the given date is not exit execute if condition 
    {

        $content .= "<font color='red'>";
        $content .= "<br>";
        $content .= "No records Found In The Database"; 
        $content .= "<br>";
        $content .= "</font>";
        return $content;

    }
```

so create a variable, append the html to it and return it back every time you need to. that should work

And i guess this will do, tested and let me know::::

```
<?php
require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

   $date=date("m/d/Y");
   echo "Today Date Is = ";
   echo "$date";
   echo "<h1><center>Midrange, Turnover For All The Accounts </center></h3>";


    //include("../../../../../../../inetpub/wwwroot/dbcon/connection.php");
    //WHY DO YOU NEED THIS TO BE TWICE?

function content()
{   

    //init the content variable
    $content = null;

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
         include("../../../../../../../inetpub/wwwroot/dbcon/connection.php");

         $content .= "<h3>Turnover For Apria</h3>";

         $search=htmlspecialchars($_POST['search']);
         $selectcondition = "SELECT * FROM customer.order where DATE='".$search."'"; //Select Query Which check the whether the TURNOVER for the given INCIDENT is exit or not.

         $check=mysql_query($selectcondition,$con);
         $fetch=mysql_fetch_row($check); 

    if(!$fetch)                         //If checklist for the given date is not exit execute if condition 
    {

        $content .= "<font color='red'>";
        $content .= "<br>";
        $content .= "No records Found In The Database"; 
        $content .= "<br>";
        $content .= "</font>";

        return $content;

    }

     else //if the above condition is flase !

     {

        $sql= "select * from customer.order where DATE='".$_POST['search']."'";


        $mydata=mysql_query($sql,$con);
        //$fetch_rows=mysql_fetch_row($mydata);

         $content .= "<table class='mytable' width='100%' height='10%' border='1' cellspacing='0'>

                     <tr>
                      <th>DATE</th>
                      <th>ORDER</th>
                      <th>SUTNAME</th>
                      <th> COMMENTS</th>

                     </tr>";

        while($records = mysql_fetch_array($mydata))

        {

            $content .= "<tr>";
                    $content .= "<td>" . $records['TIMESTAMPS'] . "&nbsp;</td>";
                    $content .= "<td>" . $records['ORDER']. "&nbsp;</td>";
                    $content .= "<td>" . $records['CUSTNAME'] . "&nbsp;</td>";
                    $content .= "<td align='center'>";
                    $content .= '<textarea  name="textarea" cols="100"  >'.$records['COMMENTS'].'</textarea><br>'; 
            $content .= "</td>";

        }

    }

          $content .= "</table>";

          return $content;
    }


  $html=content();
  if($html){
      $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
      $dompdf->load_html($html);
      $dompdf->render();
      $dompdf->stream("order.pdf");
  }else{
    echo "Look like something is wrong here .";
  }


?>
```

**Second UPDATE**

this sample is working, make sure you have included all proper files and fix all the syntax errors like one extra `}` also please change to `mysqli_*`

```
<?php
$html=content();
if($html){
  require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");
  $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
  $dompdf->load_html($html);
  $dompdf->render();
  $dompdf->stream("order.pdf");
}else{

  echo "Look like something is wrong here .";
}
function content(){
    $content = null;
    $content .= "<table class='mytable' width='100%' height='10%' border='1' cellspacing='0'>

                     <tr>
                      <th>DATE</th>
                      <th>ORDER</th>
                      <th>SUTNAME</th>
                      <th> COMMENTS</th>

                     </tr>";

  $content .= "</table>";

  return $content;
}
$date=date("m/d/Y");
echo "Today Date Is = ";
echo "$date";
echo "<h1><center>Midrange, Turnover For All The Accounts </center></h3>";
?>
```

it has to be processed in this order since it has to respect the header in php and this sample will generate the proper pdf that can be opened, just need to populate with the right data

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
so do i need to remove echo from the code

Comment: I have removed the **content function** , and took everything in $**content** variable after made those changes a corrupted pdf is generated, Please find the modified code below.

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
       include("../../../../../../../inetpub/wwwroot/dbcon/connection.php");
          
  if(!$fetch)                
  {
  $content .=   "<font color='red'>";
  $content .=   "<br>";
  $content .=  "No order Found In The Database"; 
  $content .=  "<br>";
  $content .=   "</font>";
  return $content;
   
  }

Comment: I unable to paste my whole code , because "comment" option restricted me with words limit , is there is any ways so that i can paste my whole code here. so that it will be easier for you to figure out the problem?.

Comment: it may be corrupt for what i can see becuase you never create the `$content` variable, you just append to something that doesnt exist ..

Comment: just edit your original question and put it there ;)

Comment: I updated my code with the changes, Please look into it.

Comment: you cant have `return` when there is not function since the if will stop right there and is returning to nothing. so i would keep it inside a function, try the sample i updated

Comment: I have made the exact changes after saw your post and also added the function but still corrupted PDF is generated.

Comment: @Ashish check the updated answer, here is small sample how is working http://jorgerodriguez.dk/te/

Comment: After clicking on your suggested link an pdf is open in which only the output is their not exact code.

Comment: @Ashish the code for that is in my answer in the last update, the bottom ;)

Comment: I meant php code ? which used to generate the output, Because i tried but mine is generated a corrupted file.

Comment: @Ashish look at my answer, it says **Second UPDATE** that is the code generating that pdf ;)

Comment: i copied and paste your exact code but don't know why my corrupted file is generated :( still the corrupted pdf file is 3 kb of size ..

Comment: @Ashish them i cant help you more mate, maybe you are missing some files for the library or your server has a really old php version. or something

Comment: @Ashish Also remember to accept the answer if you feel like i help you ;)

Comment: finally managed to export the files is generated successfully, little more help i need. 

I am working with multiple databases, and want to export file of all database in one pdf. for that what i need to do . 

Do i need to start another topic for that ??

Comment: @Ashish yes you do :)

Comment: Ok i am raising the another topic for that.

Comment: I raised the topic , Please look into it SIR.

Comment: @Ashish if mine help was good, dont forget to accept the answer :)